# Java web: Load another data into second <select> when selection changed for first <select>

Tags: html, database, jsp, servlets

One .jsp contains two `<select>` items. When selection changed in first `<select>`, items that second `<select>` contains should be reloaded from database. How can I do it without page reloading/redirect?

E.g. see any airline site: when you select departure city (airport), items of second dropbox are updated.

Comment: Do you want as just to give you an approach on how to do this or an example as well?

Comment: `"How can i do it without page reloading/redirect?"` No matter what it is, the answer to that (when triggered from the client side) is always Ajax.

Comment: @developerwjk thank you